# APi call get method

Tags: python, api

I have the pieces of a puzzle but I ma not able to make it. I have the following info from the API I want to query.

Target domains:
https://api.ethplorer.io/ for mainnet
https://kovan-api.ethplorer.io/ for testnet (Kovan)
Method GET

And I tried the following code but of course it did not work. Please be kind. Any hint or help would be appreciated.

```
import urllib.request
contents = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.ethplorer.io/").read()
/getAddressInfo/{*********}
```

Edit:
the correct code is:

```
import urllib.request
contents = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/**********************************?apiKey=freekey").read()
```

Comment: Typing the URL into a browser gives me an error message.  Meanwhile, using https://google.com/ in your above code works just fine.  Are you sure you have the right URL?

Comment: @FrankYellin thanks for you comment. The url comes from the doc here. https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API#get-address-info

Comment: It says `Each request should have a mandatory apiKey parameter.` so your request url should be sth like `https://api.ethplorer.io/getLastBlock?apiKey=your_api_key`

Comment: @Frank THank you so much. You put me on the right track. It is working